# Not binding variable changes inside callback Angular 2 + NativeScrip

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have an ActivityIndicator that shows/hide when login occurs.

[image]

The problem that when i change the value of isAuthenticating inside a callback function, the value seems not to been changed.

[image]

The alert dialog appear normaly, but the ActivitatorIndicator still visible.

**UPDATE**

The problem was on my component declaration.
[image]

solved by removing the line

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

Comment: Post the contents of `ActivityIndicator` component

Comment: is a nativescript component:

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/activity-indicator

Comment: when busy = true, the activatorindicator is visible, when busy = false, the activiatorindicator is hidden.

Comment: can you able to create plnkr

Comment: the component is indifferent, i've tried with label and text components, but the variable still not changing.

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of as screenshot. Screenshots are great, but only in addition to the source as text

Comment: I suspect the `userService` somehow executes code outside Angulars zone and therefore Angular doesn't run change detection. You can check by injecting `constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}` and then run `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` after the line with the red arrow.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks a lot, i identified the problem and updated my question with the answer. Your comment help me a lot.